# Laravel query for getting top 10 records with maximum amount

Tags: mysql, laravel

I want to get the top 10 records based on the maximum amount. I have tried with the below code

```
1)  $topclaims = Claim::take(10)->max('estimated_loss')->get()   

           // giving me an error Call to a member function get() on string

2)  $topclaims = Claim::take(10)->orderBy('estimated_loss','DESC')->get();

           //this one is working but not getting an exact result

3) $topclaims = Claim::orderBy('estimated_loss','DESC')->limit(10)->get(); 

     //this one is also working but not getting an exact result
```

I want like this

```
first record = 10,
second = 9,
third = 8,
fourth = 7,
fifth = 6


the result I am getting is 

first record = 9,
second = 8,
third = 10,
fourth = 6,
fifth = 7
```

Comment: What do you mean by "not getting an exact result"? Is it approximated? Is the ordering not done properly?

Comment: Can you describe your data a bit more? Is `estimated_loss` a column in your table?

Comment: @NicoHaase yes, it is not coming in order

Comment: @apokryfos yes, estimated_loss is a column with varchar(191) datatype

Comment: you should change it to INT otherwise you're going to be sorting alphabetically rather than numerically

Comment: @apokryfos yes you are right after changing to integer type it is working

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to convert `estimated_loss` as int first to sort.

```
$topclaims = Claim::orderByRaw("CAST(estimated_loss as UNSIGNED) DESC")->limit(10)->get();
```